# Security issues and theft of money from the wallet

Tags: security, wallet-security

A transaction was sent from my node night

```
CTransaction(hash=27aac94405, ver=2, vin.size=7, vout.size=1, nLockTime=762357)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(85d4e6a81c, 0), scriptSig=, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(d12a5e7187, 25), scriptSig=160014726d057ab1044dd6e5, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(881db86218, 4), scriptSig=1600146ef598af918c5a9064, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(e283c68eb8, 0), scriptSig=16001479d36f7d700d72585e, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(51621fad57, 3), scriptSig=1600140991872d83fb837016, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(7279e53877, 0), scriptSig=16001493140918fbfffe911a, nSequence=4294967294)
    CTxIn(COutPoint(e0f1c812ee, 1), scriptSig=1600140736f7fe48402d316a, nSequence=4294967294)
    CScriptWitness(3044022021d7de713db46be968cfae24dae82bd199767972593ab5936bb4f856b13eea1002204c36bd0eefd45e74f19da9dc6bd9543b8c58491d6edf7eec7e9a47941c32531d02, 023eb124f7e1cf221416a10c91fdad8fbd0b75442e510ea7c0799d77d9f7e2c5c5)
    CScriptWitness(304402206f8e67d41822a7913a40a64369de71ece60814900ae517045867ce182e1f310c02206db1d613741939b85ab8977f2f05dc0371a4da19bce7f843414b403c739198ea02, 02bf2925f6cc07d5942916f70bcea96c8644a756cea5cf5bf097fce9f5ded68327)
    CScriptWitness(304402201bd671f87d5d0e5c4f69e38f7f067a2416ed6eba674aaa65bef068a46e295d2702203833cc2a032210d34cccfeca2fdb6bf3381302171907c78c67d043b7710ea1d302, 032aa52f8534a0269c756193f1b5a6ab759364150afaecef83c63d6cbc38adf292)
    CScriptWitness(304402203ae1fb440e6f3630a0c0773263a7eb7f502263553082cfc2074ce490f501c82b0220436ada44af74391c8c4acddd42b6830260e55f87c9fc1bf228752f14ac5c1cb902, 02ddf12cbd487fcd91c7cc4c2556194fa7117c8be3f108a7cb0b7c8ccba17a9d72)
    CScriptWitness(3044022058ea08b1a863989e941391583669d225685a734672a730865434239859f7041c022042b5f2b97f093e1d2e90c71f6344dc93a68f6a3bc6af38bceadda17942944ba302, 0395232ba2deb14b15c0475524e43cf1583dbd4eaf0c361a08bf009341edbe3d2c)
    CScriptWitness(304402206ed1becaf62ad97b0bfe26dc673b6e5027ca5cfc85976e63b4d1e9f41f99fe3b02205b3434bbad54e5c9ab4b6eb7dca71761535486189627b54189bb051712c0d60802, 03798f0bff406228d85a65d5bc4139a801766d5ae939aff70b028abccf3ad5611a)
    CScriptWitness(304402206efd5019016bfc300eea812ccc95e45faa4e7f927f4b7f79c09e2f08fbf823c102203aa3d05758082fb88d6fcc7087fc1d373acd1140c4ac6aeefdfd1e6f5ef6fe7602, 0206ecb5b628da0cb8b07ce9ace1c62a7eb1f4b34a0d004f7413732146e05ba811)
    CTxOut(nValue=0.08658863, scriptPubKey=76a9140defb8e8a5f44458e472d4e0)
2022-11-09T01:48:04Z [wallet.dat] AddToWallet 27aac9440529f4f29748e546d33bf8e1c20895649b192aba2e1aab1d5aa0455a  newupdate
2022-11-09T01:48:04Z [wallet.dat] Submitting wtx 27aac9440529f4f29748e546d33bf8e1c20895649b192aba2e1aab1d5aa0455a to mempool for relay
2022-11-09T01:48:04Z [wallet.dat] AddToWallet 27aac9440529f4f29748e546d33bf8e1c20895649b192aba2e1aab1d5aa0455a
```

I am confused. First of all, I started looking for any logs and clues on the server, but were unsuccessful.
In the RCP node config, the server is configured only locally.
Node version is 23.0.0

https://blockchair.com/bitcoin/transaction/27aac9440529f4f29748e546d33bf8e1c20895649b192aba2e1aab1d5aa0455a

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

> Any ideas?

It looks like the computer running your node has been compromised. Either someone else has physical access to it or someone has introduced malware onto it.